# TSQL get all orders that have specific code in history

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table that holds status changes for orders:

```
ORDER_ID  |  CHANGE_DATE      |  CODE_1  |  CODE_2  |  CODE_3
=============================================================
1         |  2012-09-01 12:20 |  Z1      |  NULL    |  NULL
1         |  2012-09-01 12:21 |  Z2      |  S01     |  NULL
1         |  2012-09-01 12:22 |  Z2      |  S04     |  NULL
2         |  2012-09-01 12:22 |  Z1      |  S01     |  NULL
3         |  2012-09-01 12:23 |  Z1      |  S03     |  NULL
1         |  2012-09-01 12:24 |  Z1      |  S02     |  NULL
2         |  2012-09-01 12:29 |  Z1      |  S05     |  NULL
1         |  2012-09-01 13:29 |  Z5      |  T01     |  X01
2         |  2012-09-01 13:31 |  Z1      |  T01     |  NULL
```

I need to select ORDER_ID for every order that has in history CODE_2 IN (S01,S02,S03) but don't have S04 and S05 after them.

In this specific case query should return order 1 because after CODE_2 there is no S04 and S05, please notice that order 1 had S04 in history, but after that it had code S02.
It should also return order 3 because of code S03.
Order 2 shouldn't be returned because last code in his history is S05 (last from S group).

Can I do this without joining to other table? I would like to select ORDER_ID only from this table.

Comment: By what columns can you say that order 1 had an `S02` "after" its `S04`. The `S04` has a later datetime value, which is the only obvious column to order by.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Sorry for that tiny error, I've already fixed this.

Comment: I've updated the sample data in my answer and verified that it now returns orders 1 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

If `CHANGE_DATE` is, in fact, the column that allows rows to be ordered, then the following suffices:

```
declare @T table (ORDER_ID int,CHANGE_DATE datetime,CODE_1 char(2),CODE_2 char(3),CODE_3 char(3))
insert into @T(ORDER_ID,CHANGE_DATE,CODE_1,CODE_2,CODE_3) values
(1,'2012-09-01T12:20:00','Z1',NULL,NULL),
(1,'2012-09-01T12:21:00','Z2','S01',NULL),
(1,'2012-09-01T12:22:00','Z2','S04',NULL),
(2,'2012-09-01T12:20:00','Z1','S01',NULL),
(3,'2012-09-01T12:21:00','Z1','S03',NULL),
(1,'2012-09-01T12:24:00','Z1','S02',NULL),
(2,'2012-09-01T12:29:00','Z1','S05',NULL),
(1,'2012-09-01T13:23:00','Z5','T01','X01'),
(2,'2012-09-01T13:31:00','Z1','T01',NULL)

select distinct ORDER_ID from @T t where CODE_2 in ('S01','S02','S03')
and not exists(
    select * from @T t2 where
        t.ORDER_ID = t2.ORDER_ID and
        t2.CODE_2 in ('S04','S05') and
        t2.CHANGE_DATE > t.CHANGE_DATE
    )
```

Comment: I'll check this right away, sorry for that bug at first place :)